# XML append node with main element

Tags: c#, xml

Hi all I have my XML as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicantDetails>
</ApplicantDetails>
```

I am adding dynamically the nodes based on few searches as follows

```c#
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = xDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlElement elem = null;
XmlElement e = xDoc.CreateElement("ApplicantData");
e.InnerText = string.Empty;
root.AppendChild(e);
xDoc.Save(path);
elem = xDoc.CreateElement("Mobile");
elem.InnerText = txtMobile.Text;
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("ApplicantData");
node.AppendChild(elem);
xDoc.Save(path);
```

Which is giving my XML as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicantDetails>
  <ApplicantData>
    <Mobile>1234567890</Mobile>
  </ApplicantData>
</ApplicantDetails>
```

Now I would like to add a new node as follows

```xml
<ApplicantData>
    <Mobile>1000000</Mobile>
</ApplicantData>
```

But with the code I have written it is appending as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicantDetails>
  <ApplicantData>
    <Mobile>1234567890</Mobile>
    <Aadhar>
    </Aadhar>
    <Mobile>1234567801</Mobile>
  </ApplicantData>
  <ApplicantData>
  </ApplicantData>
</ApplicantDetails>
```

Comment: I *presume* that in your first code block, there is a break (e.g. waiting for an event or something?) after the first `xDoc.Save(path);`? In any case, you write "But with the code I have written it is appending as follows", but you are not showing that code (the code that inserts an `<Aadhar>` element, among other things), so we have no way of telling what is wrong.

Comment: Can you add your method completely please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `XmlElement` use `XmlNode`

```
XmlNode ApplicantData = xDoc.CreateElement("ApplicantData");
XmlNode elem = null;
XmlNode e = xDoc.CreateElement("ApplicantData");
e.InnerText = string.Empty;
elem = xDoc.CreateElement("Mobile");
elem.InnerText = txtMobile.Text;
ApplicantData.AppendChild(elem);
xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ApplicantData);                    
xDoc.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to create dynamic xml.

```
XElement xmldata = new XElement("ApplicantDetails",
           new XElement("ApplicantData", new XElement("Mobile", 1234567890)),
           new XElement("ApplicantData", new XElement("Mobile", 1234567801))
        );
```

Comment: But I am not adding all data at a time, in that case how can I use this

Comment: @Learner how did you add the second mobile element, your code not showing how the second mobile element added

Comment: The one I needed is I need a dynamic way to add n number of elements `<ApplicantData>
    <Mobile>1234567890</Mobile>
    <Aadhar>
    </Aadhar>
    <Mobile>1234567801</Mobile>
  </ApplicantData>`

Comment: @Learner if you add n number of elements it should work, if you're iterating the entire code. XmlElement e = xDoc.CreateElement("ApplicantData");
e.InnerText = string.Empty;
root.AppendChild(e);
xDoc.Save(path);
elem = xDoc.CreateElement("Mobile");
elem.InnerText = txtMobile.Text;
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("ApplicantData");
node.AppendChild(elem);

Comment: But I have a Form where user will enter data like `Mobilenumber address` and all so when he clicks on save I need to create the tag as mentioned like that I need to achieve. But the code I written is not working that way

Comment: The OP is using the types from `System.Xml` (i.e. `XmlDocument` & Co.). If you present a solution with a different set of types (from `System.Xml.Linq`, i.e. `XDocument` & Co.), you should at least point that out and add a warning that your answer may not be seamlessly applicable.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper will consider it